# creating a dynamic filter in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where by the code in the multi conditional filter is dependent on the user input. So if "all" is selected we see everything and if the selected input equals anything else, we only see data for that input.

the if statements insert code into the dplyr filter.

I hope I explained this properly, Any help would be appreciated, see code below:

Server

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {


 raw <- diamonds



  output$cutlist <- renderUI({

  cutlist <- sort(unique(as.vector(raw$cut)), decreasing = FALSE)
  cutlist <- append(cutlist, "All", after =  0)
  selectizeInput("cutchoose", "Cut:", cutlist)

 })


  output$colorlist <- renderUI({

colorlist <- sort(unique(as.vector(raw$color)), decreasing = FALSE)
colorlist <- append(colorlist, "All", 0)
selectizeInput("colorchoose", "color:", colorlist)

})


   output$table <- renderDataTable({



   if(input$colorchoose == "All") {

  filt1 <- quote(color != "@?><")


} else {

  filt1 <- quote(color == input$colorchoose) 

}


if (input$cutchoose == "All") {

  filt2 <- quote(cut != "@?><")


} else {

  filt2 <- quote(cut == input$cutchoose)

}



  raw %>%
  filter_(filt1) %>%
  filter_(filt2)


   })

   })
```

UI

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(

 # Application title
 titlePanel("Dynamic Filter Test App"),


  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
   uiOutput("cutlist"),
   uiOutput("colorlist")
   ),


mainPanel(
  dataTableOutput("table")
   )
  )
 ))
```

console

```
  Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  Stack trace (innermost first):
  79: renderDataTable [D:\Independent Learning\R 
       code\dynamFilter/server.R#44]
  78: func
  77: origRenderFunc
   76: output$table
    1: runApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({

    req(input$colorchoose)
    req(input$cutchoose)
    if(input$colorchoose == "All") {

      filt1 <- quote(color != "@?><")


    } else {

      filt1 <- paste0("color == ","'",input$colorchoose,"'") 

    }


    if (input$cutchoose == "All") {

      filt2 <- quote(cut != "@?><")


    } else {

      filt2 <- paste0("cut == ","'",input$cutchoose,"'")

    }



    raw %>%
      filter_(filt1) %>%
      filter_(filt2)


  })
```

The req statments in the beginning prevents the renderDataTable to be fully evaluted untill the inputs are properly initliezed. The second problem was that the input variable didn't seem to be in the scope for the dynamic evaluation of filter, hence I changed the statement to include the value of these variables rather then thier names.

Comment: Hi Bertil, Thanks for your help but this did not work for me either

Comment: Hi bertil, I tried the code on another device and it works!.....just seems to be the device I am on...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once. I think the cause is that the `renderUI` expressions aren't necessarily evaluated in time to produce the `input` values you need for your `if` statements. Since there isn't really any reactive value in your `renderUI` expressions for the `selectInput()`s, you can just put those in the `ui` script and take them out of the `server` script.

This works for me:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

raw <- diamonds
cutlist <- sort(unique(as.vector(raw$cut)), decreasing = FALSE) %>%
  append("All", after =  0)
colorlist <- sort(unique(as.vector(raw$color)), decreasing = FALSE) %>%
  append("All", 0)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$colorchoose == "All") { 
      filt1 <- quote(color != "@?><")
      } else { filt1 <- quote(color == input$colorchoose) }
    if (input$cutchoose == "All") { 
      filt2 <- quote(cut != "@?><")
      } else { filt2 <- quote(cut == input$cutchoose) }
    filter_(raw, filt1) %>% filter_(filt2) } ) }

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Filter Test App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("cutchoose", "Cut:", cutlist),
      selectizeInput("colorchoose", "color:", colorlist) ),
    mainPanel( dataTableOutput("table") ) ) ) )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried this, unfortunately no joy! thanks for your help though

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tried this on another device and it works fine also!!! just my device so

Comment: Cool, if it answers your question, mark my answer (or Bertil's) with the check mark.